# Autocalculation of sheet using information from multiple sheets in same google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Summary tab contains project name which is the name for remaining tab names in my google sheets, and starts at row 7 as follows:

| TabName |
| --- |
| Project1 |
| Project2 |
| Project3 |

There may be up to 20 TabName defined but this is not necessary.  All project name tabs has the same format - 1 row contains the weekly start dates and column 1 has the resource names.  The information with the header row starts at Row 36 and ends at Row 61.  The following is an abbreviated view what the project name tabs would look like -

**Project1 tab**

| Person | 1-Mar-2021 | 8-Mar-2021 | 15-Mar-2021 | 22-Mar-2021 | 29-Mar-2021 | 5-Apr-2021 |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 |  |  |  |
| Jane |  | 1 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |
| Abe |  |  | 5 |  | 5 |  |  |  |  |

Project2 begins at a different Start Week from Project1 and Project3.

**Project2 tab**

| Person | 4-Jan-2021 | 11-Jan-2021 | 18-Jan-2021 | 25-Jan-2021 | 1-Feb-2021 | 8-Feb-2021 | 15-Feb-2021 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 |  |  |  |
| Mary |  | 1 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |
| Abe |  |  | 5 |  | 5 |  |  |  |  |

Project3 begins at a different Start Week from Project1 and Project2.

**Project3 tab**

| Person | 8-Feb-2021 | 15-Feb-2021 | 22-Feb-2021 | 1-Mar-2021 | 8-Mar-2021 | 15-Mar-2021 | 22-Mar-2021 | 29-Mar-2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 |  |  |
| Mary |  | 1 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| John |  |  | 5 |  | 5 |  |  |  |
| Marg |  |  |  |  |  | 3 | 3 | 3 |

Note, the start week in Row1Col2 may not be the same date for all projects.  For example, Project1 starts on Mar 1 while Project2 starts on Jan 4.  Also, not all resources are across all projects (e.g. Jane and Marg are only in one project).

In the summary tab, it should show the concatenation of all projects by resource and week in 4 different views.  Each table has a maximum of 48 rows.  The below is an example of the first table in the Weekly tab.

**Resource Weekly tab**

| Person | 4-Jan-2021 | 11-Jan-2021 | 18-Jan-2021 | 25-Jan-2021 | 1-Feb-2021 | 8-Feb-2021 | 15-Feb-2021 | 22-Feb-2021 | 1-Mar-2021 | 8-Mar-2021 | 15-Mar-2021 | 22-Mar-2021 | 29-Mar-2021 | 5-Apr-2021 |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Project3 (5) | Project1 (2) | Project1 (2) Project3 (5) | Project1 (4) | Project1 (5) | Project1 (5) | Project1 (5) |  |  |  |
| Jane |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Project1 (1) |  | Project1 (1) | Project1 (1) |  |  |  |  |
| Joe | Project2 (2) | Project2 (2) | Project2 (4) | Project2 (5) | Project2 (5) | Project2 (5) Project3 (2) | Project3 (2) | Project3 (4) | Project3 (5) | Project3 (5) | Project3 (5) | Project3 (5) |  |  |  |  |  |
| Abe |  |  | Project2 (5) |  | Project2 (5) |  |  |  |  |  | Project1 (5) |  | Project1 (5) |  |  |  |  |
| Mary |  | Project2 (1) |  | Project2 (1) | Project2 (1) | Project2 (1) | Project3 (1) |  | Project3 (1) | Project3 (1) | Project3 (1) |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Marg |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Project3 (3) | Project3 (3) | Project3 (3) |  |  |  |  |

Column 1, which contains the resource name and row 1 with the start dates are fixed (i.e. no calculation required).  Also, where a resource has more than one projects, the concatenated projects are separated by a line return.  Where the resource is identified as Remote ('Y' in the column) for a project, the time should be 2 separate entry.  The Remote entry will be prefix by an R.  For example, if on Project2, Mary worked 1 day Onsite (i.e. Remote is null/blank) and 2 days Remote on Jan 11, there would be two entries Project2 (1) new line R Project2 (2)

I would also like that the concatenation calculation does not perform if the Start Week does not have a date OR if there is no resource name defined for that row.  The Summary tab will identify the number of project tabs that exists where the concatenation calculation needs to look for data.

The second are Total Time by resource and week, which is like the first table but without the Project Name; that is, sum of all time for the week.  The 3rd table shows a similar view as the 2nd table but only time where the Remote is NULL (i.e. not 'Y').  The 4th table is the 3rd table but with the Cost multiplied to the time.

Is there a way to do this using app script?

My spreadsheet can be found at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MzCm1yeqhU1I-cvlQoTBrfzybn5ktpvxeYhnud6eXms/edit#gid=1622332657.

So from Projects -

[image]

TO

[image]

Comment: When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this. Your goal using the sample "Project" sheets is the rows from 61 to 69 in "Weekly" sheet?

Comment: Hi Tanaike.  All information in the Weekly sheet is sourced from the "Project" sheets. In the Weekly sheet, I need to build Row 2 to 50.  Like the previous spreadsheet that you did, except it needs to split the Remote hours as separate.  An example is John working on Project1 on Mar 1.  There are 2 entries for John on Mar 1 - one for Project1 (2) and another for R Project1 (1).  The R Project1 identifies the Remote hours on Project1 for John.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about the logic for retrieving your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: For the 2nd table, Row 61 to Row 109, it is the total days; that is, it sums all days for the Resource and the start week for all projects.  It doesn't care if days worked is flagged as Remote or not.

Comment: For the 3rd table, Row 116 to Row 166, it is the the sum of all days for the Resource and Start week for all projects that do not have Remote flagged as 'Y'.

Comment: For the 4th table, Row 171 to Row 219, it is the same as 3rd table except it multiplies the day by Cost for each project.

Comment: For each table, maximum row are 48 and maximum columns are 126.

Comment: I have populated the expected results from the information in the "Project" sheets.  I want the script to auto populate this.

Comment: Does this help clarify?

Comment: From "Projects" -

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about the logic for retrieving your goal. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229435/discussion-between-joyce-brown-and-tanaike).

Comment: The shared script already has the solution doesn't it?

Comment: I have solved this.  The shared script is only a simplify version of this one which has multiple tables in the spreadsheet that I want to auto-calc info based on other sheets in the spreadshet.

Comment: Can you post a solution?